# Subheader title depends on post - change to static

Tags: php

On site I have subheader, which always display last post title. I would like to have in this place static title, like "Blog" or "News".

This is the whole code of subheader:

```
<?php 
    $output = ''; 
    $sub_img = array();
    global $post;

    if(!function_exists('thmtheme_call_sub_header')){
        function thmtheme_call_sub_header(){
            global $themeum_options;
            if(isset($themeum_options['blog-banner']['url'])){
                $output = 'style="background-image:url('.esc_url($themeum_options['blog-banner']['url']).');background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;padding: 150px 0 90px;"';
                return $output;
            }else{
                 $output = 'style="background-color:'.esc_attr($themeum_options['blog-subtitle-bg-color']).';padding: 150px 0 90px;"';
                 return $output;
            }
        }
    }

    if( isset($post->post_name) ){
        if(!empty($post->ID)){ 
            $image_attached = esc_attr(get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'thm_subtitle_images', true ));
            if(!empty($image_attached)){
                $sub_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_attached , 'blog-full'); 
                $output = 'style="background-image:url('.esc_url($sub_img[0]).');background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;padding: 150px 0 90px;"';
                if(empty($sub_img[0])){
                    $output = 'style="background-color:'.esc_attr(rwmb_meta("thm_subtitle_color")).';padding: 150px 0 90px;"';
                    if(rwmb_meta("thm_subtitle_color") == ''){
                        $output = thmtheme_call_sub_header();
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(rwmb_meta("thm_subtitle_color") != "" ){
                    $output = 'style="background-color:'.esc_attr(rwmb_meta("thm_subtitle_color")).';padding: 150px 0 90px;"';
                }else{
                    $output = thmtheme_call_sub_header();
                }
            }
        }else{
            $output = thmtheme_call_sub_header();
        }
    }else{
            $output = thmtheme_call_sub_header();
        }

?>

<?php if (!is_front_page()) { ?>

<div class="sub-title" <?php echo $output;?>>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sub-title-inner">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

How can I modify the code to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of this code is generating styles for a background image or color. The title is generated in this line:

```
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

You can simply replace it with text like this:

```
<h2>Whatever</h2>
```

Comment: please analyze the code once again. If I made that change on all pages I will have this text. I would like only on Blog page static title text.

Comment: In that case  you would have to replace the_title() with a conditional statement: `if (is_(archive() || is_home()) echo 'Whatever' else the_title();`

Comment: After set this on site I have: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo: `if (is_archive() || is_home()) echo 'Whatever'; else the_title();` You should be able to debug this on your own, btw.

Comment: You are right ;) (I forgot a semicolon ;) Thank you for your help.